# Closing app on pressed hardware button back twice returns to a previous activity instead

Tags: java, android

In my main activity the user gets notified to press the hardware back button to exit the app. This works in most circumstances except for when the user dies. When the user dies it goes to a GameOverActivity. If the user presses the back button in this activity and then proceeds to press back twice on the main activity, it reopens the game over activity. Here is the code, I have declared finish() on the back button in game over activity but it doesn't seem to help.

MainScreen back to quit method:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to quit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

GameOverActivity code:

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent mainScreenActivityIntent = new Intent(GameOverActivity.this, MainScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainScreenActivityIntent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent mainScreenActivityIntent = new Intent(GameOverActivity.this, MainScreenActivity.class);
        mainScreenActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(mainScreenActivityIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Here is the logic for the collision and thus creation of GameOverActivity:

```
if (weight.getBounds().intersect(player.getBounds())) {
                player.setTouched(false);
                Intent gameOverIntent = new Intent(this.getContext(), GameOverActivity.class);
                this.getContext().startActivity(gameOverIntent);
                ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
            }
```

Comment: instead of finish() use YourActivityName.this.finish(); and try

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some confuses about [Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).
Pressing back on `GameOverActivity`  instantiates a new `mainScreenActivity`, which will produce your problem.

and in your GameOverActivity onbackpressed call super.onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    // and dont start a new activity as you are stacking MainActivity instances
    finish()
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this, but it no longer goes to MainScreenActivity. MainScreen doesn't get created.

Comment: If you have Main -> Game -> Gameover then add nohHistory flag to Game and then you won't need to override back button on Gameover activity

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a new activity and just finishing current activity, add necessary code to finish the activity which you starts from onBackPressed.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `finish()` in `MainScreen` immediately after start Activity `GameOverActivity`

Comment: GameOverActivity doesn't get created from MainScreen. MainScreen starts GameActivity which in turn creates GameOverActivity. I'll add the logic for starting GameOverActivity to the post.